# Numbapro Quickstart Guide Error

Tags: python, gpu, anaconda, numba-pro

I'm trying to follow the [NumbaPro quickstart guide](https://store.continuum.io/static/img/NumbaPro-QuickStart.pdf), but I'm getting an error when following the instructions.

Here is my situation:

- Python 2.7.6
- Cuda compilation tools v5.5.0
- conda 3.4.1
- accelerate 1.5.0
- Windows 7 Professional
- Nvidia GeForce card

My code:

```
from numbapro import vectorize, float32
@vectorize([float32(float32, float32)], target=’gpu’)
def sum(a, b):
    return a + bnnn
```

And I'm getting the following errors:

```
UnboundLocalError: Local varriable 'CudaSupportError' referenced before assignment
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is ok on my computer, my situation:

- accelerate-1.8
- cudatoolkit-6
- numbapro-0.16.0-np19py27_p0
- numbapro_cudalib-0.1-0

Seems your conda needs to be updated. Try:

```
conda update conda
conda install accelerate
```

and then run it again.